# Marker removed when component unmounts ( issue on iOS only ) react-native-maps

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using the marker in my map like this:

```
<MapView
            ref={map => (this.map = map)}
            initialRegion={{
                latitude: 37.78825,
                longitude: -122.4324,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421
            }}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            showsCompass={false}
        >
            <Marker
                image={imagePath.pin}
                coordinate={currentLatLong}
                title={formattedAddress}
                draggable
                tracksViewChanges={false}
                onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}
                onPress={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); this.onMarkerPress(); }}
                zIndex={100}
            />
            
        </MapView>
```

But whenever I move to the next screen and then go back the marker disappears completely, it works fine on android but not on iOS.
Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue only persists with customized markers with images for pins, otherwise, it's working fine.